# VB.NET LINQ or ADO Deduplication of Specific Columns in a Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable created from importing a flat file. By way of example the table might looks like the following...

```
ID    Title        Firstname        Surname        Age    Postcode     Other

----------

1     Mr           Alan             Smith          27     AB1 2BA      75S3B9
2     Mrs          Helen            Smith          25     AB1 2BA      C8FN12
3     Mr           Bob              Jones          53     TS1 2ST      L039FF
4     Mr           Alan             Smith          27     AB1 2BA      66R2WX
```

As you can see there are two identical entries for Mr Alan Smith apart from having a different ID and Other field.

I need to deduplicate the datatable on the Firstname, Surname and Postcode fields whilst ignoring the ID and Other fields. However, and this is where my research and efforts so far have failed to come up with anything, I need the resulting datatable to contain all the fields with duplicates removed.

So a deduplication of the above would look like this...

```
ID    Title        Firstname        Surname        Age    Postcode     Other

----------

1     Mr           Alan             Smith          27     AB1 2BA      75S3B9
2     Mrs          Helen            Smith          25     AB1 2BA      C8FN12
3     Mr           Bob              Jones          53     TS1 2ST      L039FF
```

Entry 4 has been removed as it was recognised as a duplicate of entry 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`, especially `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
Dim query = From row In table
            Group row By UserKeys = New With {
                Key .Firstname = row.Field(Of String)("Firstname"),
                Key .Surname = row.Field(Of String)("Surname"),
                Key .Postcode = row.Field(Of String)("Postcode")
            } Into grp = Group
            Select grp.First()
' replace table '
table = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

You:

> I still want to deduplicate using Surname and Postcode, but I may also
>   want to use say the first character of the Firstname instead of all
>   the characters in the Firstname field.

Then i would use this query:

```
Dim query = From row In table
            Let firstName = row.Field(Of String)("Firstname").Trim()
            Let surName = row.Field(Of String)("Surname").Trim()
            Let postCode = row.Field(Of String)("Postcode").Trim()
            Group row By UserKeys = New With {
                Key .initialLetter = If(firstName.Length > 0, firstName.Substring(0, 1), ""),
                Key .Surname = surName,
                Key .Postcode = postCode
            } Into grp = Group
            Select grp.First()
```

Comment: Incredibly quick Tim, I knew it would be simple using LINQ Thank you. I've tested and it works. One follow up question. If I wanted to only use say the first character or few characters of the firstname, is there an ammendment to the LINQ you gave that would do this easily or would it be best to pass it to the LINQ statement after some string manipulation?

Comment: @user3411176: what means "wanted to use only the first/few character(s)"? You want to remove duplicates according to the first characters of the firstname? However, you just have to modify the anonymous type accordingly (if you don't need to group by multiple properties you don't need it at all).

Comment: Hi Tim, what I mean is. I still want to deduplicate using Surname and Postcode, but I may also want to use say the first character of the Firstname instead of all the characters in the Firstname field. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Would this work...  "Key .Firstname = row.Field(Of String)("Firstname").Substring(0, 1)"

Comment: Yes, but you need to check if there's a `Firstname` at all.

Comment: Yes you are correct, if there is nothing in the firstname field then it fails! How to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim result = dt.AsEnumerable _
    .GroupBy(Function(x) new With _
    { _
        Key .FirstName = x("Firstname"), _
        Key .Surname = x("Surname"), _
        Key .Postcode = x("Postcode") _
    }) _
    .Select(Function(x) x.First)
```